# Misinformation in change password script in auth0

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, next.js, auth0

Excuse me,

Has anyone used Auth0 in Nextjs? I have a trouble script in the **change password** section

When tried on the **Auth0** website, it worked. But when I tried it in development, an error appeared, but the password was successfully changed. And return to **reset your password** page. Even though I have used the template provided by Auth0

This code:

```
function changePassword(email, newPassword, callback) {
  const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
  const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");
  const client = new MongoClient('mongodb+srv://admin:' + configuration.MONGODB_PASSWORD + '@cluster0.rjwkjof.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority');
  client.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) return callback(err);
    const db = client.db('itbc');
    const users = db.collection('users');
    bcrypt.hash(newPassword, 10, function (err, hash) {
      if (err) {
        client.close();
        return callback(err);
      }
      users.update({ email: email }, { $set: { password: hash } }, function (err, count) {
        client.close();
        if (err) return callback(err);
        callback(null, count > 0);
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Error:

```
Something went wrong, please try again later
```

Please enlighten me. Thanks

Comment: If there's an error please show the full text of the error and any other related details.

Comment: o.k. I have added new details on my question